# How could i reset data usage to Zero?

Tags: networking

How could i reset **data usage** to Zero in Windows10 ?
please look in photo
is there a hidden log or ini file i can edit it inside windows ?

[network data usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlOQR.png)

Comment: Click on `Usage details` there should be a `Reset` button.

Comment: @DavidPostill i clicked on it and found there is no button for this .

Comment: What version of Windows10?

Comment: 2016 is not a windows 10 version number ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Windows10 1607

Comment: [How to reset Data usage in Windows 10 - gHacks Tech News](https://www.ghacks.net/2017/07/05/how-to-reset-data-usage-in-windows-10/)

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading your system. Version 1607 is now out of support.

For Version 20H2 (Current) and then coming in 21H1 or later, the reset buttons are there.

First Screenshot is for 20H2 where I did not set any recording limits and there is nothing to be reset and the Second screenshot is for 21H1 and data is being recorded and can be reset.

*The key will be for you to update Windows to a much newer version.*

[image]

[image]